# React - passing data between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, components

This is my first try at a simple React application. Working with the Openweather API and AXIOS. I took Stephen Grider's course on Udemy and I'm trying to create something on my own now, but I still have problems when passing data between components. I have a SearchBar component and I'd love to be able to pass the input value to the parent component's state, so I can then update it with each search and render it into the DOM. However, I keep running into errors. I tried passing a function as a prop to my SearchBar component but I'm getting errors:

> setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the App component.
>
> citySearch is not defined

This is confusing to me, as I tried to copy the exact steps from the course, where it seems to be working just fine. But again, I'm very new to this so it is probably just me making some sort of a rookie mistake. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Check my code below:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

//Libraries
import axios from 'axios';

//Components
import SearchBar from './Components/search-bar';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      city: 'London',
      country: 'uk',
      temperature: 0,
      humidity: 0,
      pressure: 0
    }

    //Axios call
    let city = this.state.city;
    let country = this.state.country;
    axios
      .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${API_KEY}&q=${city},${country}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({
          city: response.data.name,
          country: response.data.name,
          temperature: response.data.main.temp,
          humidity: response.data.main.humidity,
          pressure: response.data.main.pressure
        });
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

      this.citySearch('London');
  }

  citySearch(city){
    this.setState({city})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="display-1 text-center">Weather App</h1>
        <SearchBar onSearchTermChange={citySearch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

SearchBar component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      city: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        value={this.state.city}
        onChange={this.onHandleChange}
        className="form-control mt-3"
        placeholder="Enter a city name..."
        type="text"
      />
    );
  }

  onHandleChange(city) {
    this.setState({ city });
    this.props.onSearchTermChange(city);
  }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: do the axios call in `componentDidMount`, not the constructor. you can just `this.state = { city: 'London' }` - don't use setState there.

Comment: why are you doing everything in the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This
>   usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op. Please check the code for the App component.

This is because of your `axios` call inside the constructor. Put your axios call in `componentDidMount` should resolve it

> citySearch is not defined

It is because React cannot find `citySearch` function. You should change

`<SearchBar onSearchTermChange={citySearch} />`

to

`<SearchBar onSearchTermChange={this.citySearch} />`

In order to use `citySearch` this way, you should also bind `citySearch` in your constructor

In summary:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

//Libraries
import axios from 'axios';

//Components
import SearchBar from './Components/search-bar';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      city: 'London',
      country: 'uk',
      temperature: 0,
      humidity: 0,
      pressure: 0
    }
    
    this.citySearch = this.citySearch.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    //Axios call
    let city = this.state.city;
    let country = this.state.country;
    axios
      .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${API_KEY}&q=${city},${country}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({
          city: response.data.name,
          country: response.data.name,
          temperature: response.data.main.temp,
          humidity: response.data.main.humidity,
          pressure: response.data.main.pressure
        });
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }); 
  }

  citySearch(city){
    this.setState({city})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="display-1 text-center">Weather App</h1>
        <SearchBar onSearchTermChange={this.citySearch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Don't call `setState` in your constructor, you can just initialize your state like your did. So the original `setState` in your constructor should be deleted.

---

UPDATE

To search again everytime you call `citySearch`.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

//Libraries
import axios from 'axios';

//Components
import SearchBar from './Components/search-bar';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      city: 'London',
      country: 'uk',
      temperature: 0,
      humidity: 0,
      pressure: 0
    }
    
    this.citySearch = this.citySearch.bind(this)
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    axioSearch();    
  }
  
  axioSearch(city) {
    let city = city || this.state.city;
    let country = this.state.country;
    axios
      .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${API_KEY}&q=${city},${country}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({
          city: response.data.name,
          country: response.data.name,
          temperature: response.data.main.temp,
          humidity: response.data.main.humidity,
          pressure: response.data.main.pressure
        });
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });   
  }

  citySearch(city){
    this.axioSearch(city);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="display-1 text-center">Weather App</h1>
        <SearchBar onSearchTermChange={this.citySearch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Now I'm running into another issue. Whenever I try to type into my input and console.log it, [object Object] pops up in the input, and I get some sort of a Proxy object back in the console (I read that this is a 'synthetic event'). However, my app state is still not changing.

Comment: In your `SearchBar` component, the parameter should be an event from `input`. To get the value from the event you can use `e.target.value`. So change your `onHandleChange` to `onHandleChange(env) { const city = env.currentTarget.value; this.setState(...); ...; }`

Comment: So it seems I'm getting there! The only thing I have left, is to repeat the axios request everytime I populate the input field with data. Because now, when I type something, it only changes the city name in the state, but the request does not fire again to pull the correct data from the API.

Comment: @TommyVee: a dirtied update to fetch API again every time you call `citySearch`. Be sure to modify it to fit with your application. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response once again ! Appreciate it very much. I'm getting an error ' Line 30:  'axioSearch' is not defined  no-undef' This usually happens when I forget to bind 'this' somewhere...any idea where this might be coming from?

Comment: @TommyVee: relate to React binding, there are a lot of good articles around the net. You can try to figure out why do you need to `bind` your function, or what is the best practice to do so over time. May be this link help: http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/05/22/react-and-es6-part1.html

Comment: Thank you for all the help. With a few adjustments I now have a working app. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You just setState in constructor. If you want to make a call you can put it in `componentWillMount()` or `componentDidMount()`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

//Libraries
import axios from 'axios';

//Components
import SearchBar from './Components/search-bar';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      city: 'London',
      country: 'uk',
      temperature: 0,
      humidity: 0,
      pressure: 0
    }
  }

  citySearch(city){
    this.setState({city})
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    //Axios call
    let city = this.state.city;
    let country = this.state.country;
    axios
      .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${API_KEY}&q=${city},${country}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({
          city: response.data.name,
          country: response.data.name,
          temperature: response.data.main.temp,
          humidity: response.data.main.humidity,
          pressure: response.data.main.pressure
        });
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

      this.citySearch('London');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="display-1 text-center">Weather App</h1>
        <SearchBar onSearchTermChange={citySearch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not make your axios calls in the constructor. The component is not yet mounted at this point. Do this in a componentDidMount to ensure that the component is already mounted.

Secodly, you did not bind citySearch to the App class. So in the SearchBar component, it does not know that the citySearch Method should be called from the App class. It is advisable to do this binding in the App class constructor for optimization reasons.

Lastly, I will advise you to write React in a more functional way leveraging state management frameworks like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [Flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux/)

The code below should work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

//Libraries
import axios from 'axios';

//Components
import SearchBar from './Components/search-bar';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      city: 'London',
      country: 'uk',
      temperature: 0,
      humidity: 0,
      pressure: 0
    }
    this.citySearch = this.citySearch.bind(this);
    this.citySearch('London');
  }

  citySearch(city){
    this.setState({city})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //Axios call
    let {city, country} = this.state;
    axios
      .get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${API_KEY}&q=${city},${country}`)
      .then(function(response) {
        this.setState({
          city: response.data.name,
          country: response.data.name,
          temperature: response.data.main.temp,
          humidity: response.data.main.humidity,
          pressure: response.data.main.pressure
        });
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="display-1 text-center">Weather App</h1>
        <SearchBar onSearchTermChange={citySearch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

For the searchBar component, you didn't bind onHandleChange in the SearchBar component. This will throw errors. You should do this in the searchBar constructor

```
constructor() {
     ...
     this.onHandleChange = this.onHandleChange.bind(this) //Very important you do this
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to get it to work already. And I agree that using Flux/Redux is definitely more elegant way to do stuff, I am just getting started with React so I really want to focus on the core library first before moving on to Redux/Flux :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from child components to the parent component you have to use a callback method.

Check this out. (About how to pass data from parent to child and child to parent).

I know that I'm not touching your code here (I'm sorry), but if you're interested in a different approach this works.

https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17